# How to avoid line break between two <a>'s

Tags: html, css

```html
<a href="yerlioptik.com.tr" target="”_blank”">
  <img src="http://erdemci.ticimax.net/Uploads/EditorUploads/yerli-optik-site-logo-1.jpg">
</a> &nbsp;

<a href="”https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=05346317740″" target="”_blank”">
  <img src="/Uploads/EditorUploads/yerli-optik-site-watsap.jpg" style="font-size: 13px;">
</a>
```

So i got 2 images inside 's. How do i avoid line-breaking between them?

Comment: can u plz send the html code?

Comment: The `&nbsp;` is quite useless when surrounded by other whitespace.

Comment: (OT: `target="”_blank”"` and `href="”…″"` don’t look right.)

Comment: @UtkuYıldız Don’t edit the question into an other question. If an answer isn’t working then comment on the answer, or if you have a new question then post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them inside a div and use `white-space:nowrap`:

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="nowrap">
  <a href="yerlioptik.com.tr" target="”_blank”">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x150">
  </a> &nbsp;

  <a href="”https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=05346317740″" target="”_blank”">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x150">
  </a>
</div>
```

More information about [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: ".nowrap {  white-space:nowrap;}"  how do i write this in html? because it puts it as a text when i run the code.

Comment: do you mean using a style attribute? not sure what you mean by "how do I write this in html"

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline style to prevent a line break.
Try:

```
.nowrap {
    display: inline;
    clear: none;
}
```

```
<div class="nowrap">
  <a href="yerlioptik.com.tr">
    <img src="image1"> 
  </a>

  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=05346317740″ target=" ”_blank&quot;"="">
    <img src="image2">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u show me exactly how do i use this, I'm a beginner.

Comment: please see above. if it works, please mark it as answer. thank you. :)